# logging not working properly when done from a scheduled function

Tags: python, logging, apscheduler

I was to trying log events from a scheduled job then I saw that only the errors were being printed info level logging was not there although they were working on properly in other places.

This file has the codes for logger.

```
#logger.py
import logging
import os

base_dir = "database"

logFormatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s [%(threadName)-12.12s] [%(levelname)-5.5s]  %(message)s")
logger = logging.getLogger()

fileHandler = logging.FileHandler(f"{os.path.join(os.getcwd(), base_dir)}/"
                                  f"app.log")
fileHandler.setFormatter(logFormatter)
logger.addHandler(fileHandler)

consoleHandler = logging.StreamHandler()
consoleHandler.setFormatter(logFormatter)
logger.addHandler(consoleHandler)
# logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logging.getLogger("requests").setLevel(logging.WARNING)
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
```

This is the file that I was trying.

```
#scheduler.py
from logger import logger
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
import time
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

scheduler = BackgroundScheduler(logger=logger)
scheduler.start()


def test():
    print("print from test")
    logger.info("info from test")
    logger.error("error from test")
    logger.debug("debug from test")


scheduler.add_job(test, 'date', next_run_time=datetime.now()+timedelta(seconds=5))

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
```

output as follows:

```
print from test
2022-04-22 03:14:06,125 [ThreadPoolEx] [ERROR]  error from test
```

I can't figure out what's causing this.

Comment: Why `logger.setLevel` is commented out? It should be run to see `info` and `debug` output too. This isn't related to scheduling, your logger doesn't log `info` and `debug` messages directly too. Uncomment `setLevel` and retry, please.

Comment: The point is I was getting info level log working from everywhere without setting the level explicitly. I wanted to know why it was different in this case.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, your question is: why `logging.basicConfig` not changing `logger` (which is root logger) level?

If I'm right, then the answer is in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#module-level-functions):

> This function does nothing if the root logger already has handlers configured, unless the keyword argument *force* is set to `True`.

So you need to either call `logging.basicConfig` before modifying the logger

```py
import logging
import os

base_dir = "database"

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger()

logFormatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s [%(threadName)-12.12s] [%(levelname)-5.5s]  %(message)s")

# Note that `os.path.join` is used to join paths, don't try to do it youtself
fileHandler = logging.FileHandler(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), base_dir, "app.log"))
fileHandler.setFormatter(logFormatter)
logger.addHandler(fileHandler)

consoleHandler = logging.StreamHandler()
consoleHandler.setFormatter(logFormatter)
logger.addHandler(consoleHandler)

logging.getLogger("requests").setLevel(logging.WARNING)
```

or don't bother with `basicConfig` and use `logger.setLevel` instead

```py
import logging
import os

base_dir = "database"

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

logFormatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s [%(threadName)-12.12s] [%(levelname)-5.5s]  %(message)s")

# Note that `os.path.join` is used to join paths, don't try to do it youtself
fileHandler = logging.FileHandler(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), base_dir, "app.log"))
fileHandler.setFormatter(logFormatter)
logger.addHandler(fileHandler)

consoleHandler = logging.StreamHandler()
consoleHandler.setFormatter(logFormatter)
logger.addHandler(consoleHandler)

logging.getLogger("requests").setLevel(logging.WARNING)
```

With both configurations you'll see `info` message too. Replace `logging.INFO` with `logging.DEBUG` if you need `debug` messages too.

Comment: I get your answer. Very helpful. But I was getting info level log working from everywhere without setting the level explicitly. I wanted to know why it was different in this case.